# What does this title mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, headlinese

> EU slaps down Tory leadership rivals over renegotiation remarks as Boris Johnson inches closer to Number 10

What is "rivals over"， "mark"， and "inches closer to Number 10"?

Comment: The primary verb is ***to slap down*** (to criticise, to dismiss), the subject is ***the EU***, and the object is ***Tory leadership rivals*** (they're the ones being slapped down by the EU). The adverbial clause starting with ***over*** could reasonably have started with a different but contextually synonymous alternative such as ***concerning, because of, after...*** (if it hadn't been for those "renegotiation remarks", the EU wouldn't have been critical of the rivals). This happened ***as / while*** Johnson was ***inching closer / getting nearer*** to Number 10 Downing Street (becoming PM).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Any reason that is not an answer?

Comment: @DJClayworth: I haven't *yet*, but I still might closevote as "Too Broad". OP seems to be asking about three completely separate usages here, with no evidence of having researched any of them.

Comment: To do something to someone **over** something: about To inch closer: to get closer by small degrees, i.e. inches.

Comment: It isn't "rivals over" but "leadership rivals" — "over (about) renegotiation".

Comment: Number 10 is a reference to the Prime Ministers Residence and office, at #10 Downing St, in Westminster London. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_Downing_Street so it means Boris is trying to make progress toward becoming the next prime minister.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thanks a lot. This is a great answer despite the question issue.